# Can't make code folding in dart (flutter) with vs code for specific blocks

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, folding, code-folding

I'm trying to make a code folding for the "for loop" and for "if statement " in flutter with vs code but i can't .however the code folding works well if i try to fold the hole class or the body of a method...

is that a bug in Dart or i have something wrong with my config

code folding isn't working here to fold if statement:

[image: code folding isn't working here]

code folding works here to fold a method :
[image]

Comment: //#region and //#endregion work in the Android Studio and Intellij as well.
Use those IDEs if you want to have code folding

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, folding is done by dart and not vscode, and is supposed to be this way since version 2.13.
Source: https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-13/#improved-folding

Comment: Yes , but it's weired that dart dont implement loops , if statements ... folding . those things are basics